# Get common values in a multidimension array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

hope you're doing well
I have an multidimensional array whose output is given below

```
[888] => Array
    (
        [team_name] => freight
        [total] => 7707103.66482
    )

[887] => Array
    (
        [team_name] => freight
        [total] => 6954528.9139
    )

[890] => Array
    (
        [team_name] => assembly line
        [total] => 1953
    )
```

I want to get all the indexes in a separate array which have common team_name.

Comment: basically what i want is to match all the team_name which are same and then add there total. for example in this case this array has 2 "freight" now get there total and add them 7707103.66482 + 6954528.9139

Comment: If should not be necessary to add comments to clarify your question.  (Stackoverflow provides an [edit] option for that )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this could do the job:

```
$result = [];
foreach($yourArray as $ar) {
    if (isset($result[$ar['team_name]])) {
        $result[$ar['team_name']] += $ar['total'];
    } else {
        $result[$ar['team_name']] = $ar['total'];
    }
}
```

The $result-array should then look like this (not tested though!):

```
array(
    'freight' => 7707103.66482 + 6954528.9139,
    'assebly line' => 1953
)
```

Comment: Thanks alot. now i can have some peace :)